# key event triggers and moving objects on screen

Tags: python, pygame

So I am making a game with the pygame module in python. The game is [Breakout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakout_(video_game)). One of the mechanics of the game is move the player left and right. How am I doing this is when the user presses the left or right arrow key, the player brick moves the left or right depending on what key is pressed, but the catch is that it if the player presses and holds the left or right button; the player brick will not continue to move... My question is how do I make the player brick continue to move instead of moving once when the key button is held down?!

here is my code

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
#colors
BLACK    = (   0,   0,   0)
WHITE    = ( 255, 255, 255)
GREEN    = (   0, 255,   0)
RED      = ( 255,   0,   0)

#the Brick
class goodbrick:
    def __init__ (self, color):
        self.color_scheme=color
        ##################X,  Y     L    F
        self.cordinates= [20, 450, 100, 0]

    def move (self, x):
            self.cordinates[0]+=x

    def draw (self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color_scheme, self.cordinates, 0)


#class enemyBrick:
#the ball

#pygame stuff
size = (700, 500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("BREAKOUT")
done= False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#init stuff
player1= goodbrick(GREEN)
#main loop
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get(): # User did something
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done=True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player1.move(-1)
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player1.move(1)
        elif event.type ==pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player1.move(-1)
                print("yup")
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player1.move(1)
    #art
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    player1.draw()
    #screent
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
#colors
BLACK    = (   0,   0,   0)
WHITE    = ( 255, 255, 255)
GREEN    = (   0, 255,   0)
RED      = ( 255,   0,   0)

#the Brick
class goodbrick:
    def __init__ (self, color):
        self.color_scheme=color
        ##################X,  Y     L    F
        self.cordinates= [20, 450, 100, 0]

    def move (self, x):
            self.cordinates[0]+=x

    def draw (self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color_scheme, self.cordinates, 0)


#class enemyBrick:
#the ball

#pygame stuff
size = (700, 500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("BREAKOUT")
done= False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#init stuff
player1= goodbrick(GREEN)
#main loop
change = 0
while not done:        
    for event in pygame.event.get(): # User did something
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done=True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                change = -1                
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                change = 1
        elif event.type ==pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                change = 0
                print("yup")
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                change = 0
    player1.move(change)
    #art
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    player1.draw()
    #screent
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: elif event.type ==pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                change = 0
                print("yup")
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                change = 0

Comment: I did what i understood, from question statement.  I have corrected my answer according to your comment

Comment: Thank you very much